# Alignment issue in the search result page - tag information section

Tags: feature-request, tags, design, search

If I'm searching a query with one tag alone, in the search result page the tag information section is not properly aligned. Can be the tag information section added with appropriate margin to aligned correctly.

Sample search queries: [1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bbug%5D+is%3Aq), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bdesign%5D+is%3Aa)

Screenshot with current and expected UI:

> [image: Search results]